# Can't get element by id

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

I have the following code and I can't understand what is wrong.

```
<tr id="outState">
    <th>State</th>
    <td style="text-align: center;" id="stateRow_0" xmlns="">
        <select id="state_0">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Output:

```
alert(document.getElementById("outState"));
alert(document.getElementById("stateRow_0 "));
alert(document.getElementById("state_0"));
```

The first gives me null and the second succeeds.
On IE9 I get on the first success and on the second null.

The JS is called after all the DOM has been loaded.

Why and how can I solve this?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RandallFlagg/NUCYH/4/)

Comment: Next time, it might be a better idea to post the actual question first, instead of AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA. Withdrawn downvote & voting to re-open.

Comment: The linked jsfiddle works just fine. It's not the same as the code posted here, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the second alert has an extra space at the end, causing the `getElementById` to fail..

```
alert(document.getElementById("stateRow_0 "));
                                         ^
```

if you remove it, it will work just fine..

Comment: @RandallFlagg It works fine for me with this part fixed.. check out http://jsfiddle.net/NUCYH/1/

Comment: My problem was somewhere else but I did learn that JSFiddle needs the tag table. thanks

Comment: @RandallFlagg, a yes.. i added that instinctively before even checking the code.. good catch!